# SQL joining on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, join

Say you have a query like:

```
Select A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 as A left join Table2 as B
on (A.column1=B.column3 or A.column2=B.column3)
```

Is this the same as the concatenation of the two queries:

```
Select A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 as A left join Table2 as B
on (A.column1=B.column3)

Select A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 as A left join Table2 as B
on (A.column2=B.column3)
```

Or will there be differences in the final table?

Comment: Is there something else you're trying to ask that can't be discovered by simply trying it yourself?

Comment: Did you run the queries and see if you get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

These two queries would have the same result set:

```
Select DISTINCT A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 A left join
     Table2 as B
     on A.column1 = B.column3 or A.column2 = B.column3;
```

And:

```
Select A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 A left join
     Table2 B
     on A.column1 = B.column3
union  -- Note:  NOT UNION ALL
Select A.column1, A.column2, B.column3
from Table1 A left join
     Table2 B
     on A.column2 = B.column3 ;
```

Without the `distinct` and `union`, you have all sorts of duplicates that might arise (or not) between the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean the same as the union of the tables since there is no concatenation in SQL

No they will not be the same -- the union has a chance to have duplicates if there is a row where both `A.column1 = B.column3` and `A.column2 = B.Column3`

Comment: A UNION wouldn't have duplicates, but a UNION ALL might.

Comment: @TabAlleman - True, since he said concatenation I assumed he meant union all, but didn't type that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use UNION or UNION ALLdepending on the results you want to have (UNION ALL is faster but it may contain duplicates). Either one is usually faster tha using OR. Just make sure you run the result sets for both and pick the one with the same results as the orginal query.